# how to use json file in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have the following JSON file and using it while creating users in terraform

```
{
    "SRE@abc.com" : [
        {
        "name" : "abc",
        "description" : 100,
        },        
        {
        "name" : "efg",
        "description" : 100
        },        
        {
        "name" : "wer",
        "description" : 100
        }
    ],
    "SDE@abc.com" : [
        {
        "name" : "xyz",
        "description" : 100
        },
        {
        "name" :  "qwe",
        "description" : 100        
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried with a few things but it errors out ... while usin in the resource creation. I'm unable to figure out on how to grab the keys, values

```
resource "oci_identity_user" "users" {
    count = keys(local.users)[*] 
    
    compartment_id = var.tenancy_ocid
    description = count.index[description]
    name = count.index[name]
    email = count.index[email]
}


Error: Invalid index
│
│   on local.tf line 14, in locals:
│   14:   services = keys(local.users[1])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.odsc_serivices is object with 2 attributes
│
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two lists in your `users` object, you have to concatenate them. You can do this with combining [`flatten`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten) and [`values`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values) functions. Moreover, I suggest using `for_each` instead of `count`:

```
resource "oci_identity_user" "users" {
  for_each = { for index, value in flatten(values(local.users)) : index => value }

  compartment_id = var.tenancy_ocid
  description    = each.value.name
  name           = each.value.description
  email          = each.value.email
}
```

Update:

```
resource "oci_identity_user" "users" {
  for_each = {
    for index, value in flatten([
      for email, value in local.users : [
        for user in value : { email : email, name : user.name, description : user.description }
      ]
    ]) : index => value
  }

  compartment_id = var.tenancy_ocid
  description    = each.value.name
  name           = each.value.description
  email          = each.value.email
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ervin Szilagyi. How can we get  "users_set1" and  "users_set2". Is that something each.index or each.index[0]

Comment: I apologize. I updated the JSON in the question. Email-id is on the top and I need to grab the email from the top.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please don't modify your question. Instead post a new one, so other people will be able to see it.